# Is there a cleaner way to part fill a tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with a custom cell with two labels and two UITextFields, some times my tableView will have X number of rows, but I will only need to fill the first three UITextFields.

To get around this I'm currently checking for differences `cellForRowAt` and appending empty strings like so

```
if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > someArray.count {
                var difference = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - someArray.count
                while difference > 0 {
                    someArray.append("")
                    difference -= 1
                }
```

While this works it doesn't feel very elegant and was hoping to find a better way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your view is not your model. Decorate the cell according to that test with an empty string in `cellForIndexPath` as opposed to messing with your model data to get the empty rows.

Comment: Generally, the array count should be the same as the `UITableViews` number of rows. Instead of having this logic, update your array to reflect what you want displayed in the `UITableView`.

Comment: @WarrenBurton This code Ive shared is within cellForRowAt if thats what you mean?

Comment: @bbarnhart unfortunately thats not possible, as data is still displayed in the other cells, it's just sometimes some of the data is less than the main data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to just set the text field text property to "" if the index is greater then or equal to the size of someArray:

```
cell.textField.text = indexPath.row < someArray.count ? someArray[indexPath.row] : ""
```

Which is what I think they are suggesting in the comments.

It appears you would just like to clean up your code, and have a cleaner way to fill an array with a default value.  I would use the `Array.init(repeating repeatedValue: Element, count: Int)` like so:

```
let difference = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - someArray.count
if difference > 0 {
    someArray.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating:"", count: difference))
}
```

You could get really **cute** and create a Array extension to do it for you:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func append(repeating repeatedValue: Element, count: Int) {
        if count > 0 {
            append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: repeatedValue, count: count))
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
someArray.append(repeating: "", count: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - someArray.count)
```

Comment: That’s perfect, trying to keep my code concise, and the loop was spoiling it for me, thanks for the answer!